# Transfer new details from one database to another database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just upgrade the host plan to cloud, and in the mean time before the migration end and the ns changed some new data changed. How can I add this new data (users and listings) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to ask your host's technical support team for assistance with this, as it sounds like an issue that's internal to how their systems handled the migration.